# Query does full table scan even with indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g

I am having a simple query with all  joined columns indexed but still i receive a full table scan
Following is the query

```
   select rsb.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID
   from REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_DETAILS rsd,
        rep_status_bridge rsb
   where rsd.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID = rsb.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID;
```

the columns REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID is indexed in both the tables, following is the explain plan

[Explain plan at the following link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO8tI.png)

Please assist me in resolving this issue

As many Folks have asked this is the query that is taking forever to load

```
select count(rsb.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID) from 
pcfc_dba.rep_pass rp,
pcfc_dba.rep_status_bridge rsb,
pcfc_dba.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_DETAILS rsd,
pcfc_dba.rep_status_ref rsf
where trunc(rp.APPR_ACTION_END_DATE)>=to_date('01/02/2017','dd/MM/yyyy') 
and trunc(rp.APPR_ACTION_END_DATE)<=to_date('06/02/2107','dd/MM/yyyy')
and  rp.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID = rsb.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID
and   rsb.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID=rsd.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID
and  rsf.REP_STATUS_REF_ID=rsd.REP_STATUS_REF_ID;
```

[The explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywels.png)

Comment: Since there are no single ID conditions, one table will be read from the beginning to the end, index searching the other table.

Comment: Why the join? Why not use an exists? Also, legacy join syntax is hella bad nowadays

Comment: This looks like a reasonable execution plan to me. Are you having a performance problem? If so, can you enumerate it?

Comment: Are you sure the column is indexed in the DETAILS table? Is it also marked as FK pointing to the other table? What you are reporting is indeed quite odd; I would first double-check that the columns are really indexed (rather than just believing or "knowing" they are).

Comment: @JohnHC - perhaps a semijoin as you suggest is the right solution to the OP's problem, but maybe not; in any case, EXISTS is not logically equivalent to a join.

Comment: It is not which access path is chosen that is the starting point for assessing the performance; it is the response you get.  Are you saying this is too slow ? If so what sort of response are you getting and what is the spread of data across the two tables ? What sort of response do you need ?

Comment: @mathguy. The explain plan does show an index...

Comment: @mathguy Agreed, but in the context of OP's query, it would likely perform better, no?

Comment: @JohnHC - Surely, but if for some reason the join is required for the business problem, not the semijoin, the better performance seems irrelevant. No?

Comment: How many records does REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_DETAILS have?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, @MariusCatalinJucan the table is having 1.3 mil rows. This query is actually part of a larger Query and i narrowed it down that this particular statement is causing the problem . I Wonder why the full table scan is happening.

Comment: Stale Statistics?

Comment: @RyanVincent around 1.3 million too

Comment: what´s the connection between these 2 queries?

Comment: trunc function on table column compare may be an issue?

Comment: @Sebas, the second query is the production query that is causing the problem. The 1st query is a part of the main query. Also i noticed if i removed these lines rsb.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID=rsd.REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_ID
and  rsf.REP_STATUS_REF_ID=rsd.REP_STATUS_REF_ID; From the main query the query is fast

Comment: these queries have nothing to do at all with one another and extrapolating explain plans improvements over the first one won't garantee anything for the 2nd one.

Comment: An index range scan with an estimate of 1 row is always a red flag. It *may* be accurate, but if it's not, then chances of a sub-optimal plan are high. a SQL Monitor report would be much more useful, ad we would get both estimate and actual cardinalities.

Comment: @BobC - the execution plan shows the index on the PK column in the `rsb` table. I was asking about the same column in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is a stale statistic as was said above.
The table `REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_DETAILS` has **1.3 mil** records as you said before. But in plan we see full table scan expect to get only **310 rows**( I suppose it's rows, but I don't see a header). Could you please gather statistics ec.:

```
begin 
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (
   ownname          => USER, 
   tabname          => 'REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_DETAILS', 
   cascade          => true);
end;
/
```

and then check num_rows from `all_tables` view

```
 select t.owner, t.table_name, t.num_rows 
  from all_tables t 
 where t.table_name in ('REP_STATUS_BRIDGE_DETAILS');
```

It's take in account statistic's data. After statics will be gathered you should get a different plans for both queries.

Comment: Thank you the stale stats was the issue. Thank you all for your support.