# Query do a full table scan with indexes

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a table in two schemas **Schema1** and **Schema2** with a indexed column used in a join like below

```
SELECT clog.id,
      clog.c_id,
      cdr.attr_number,
      cdr.cnumber
    FROM t_table_log clog
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT id,
        MAX(c_id) AS maxcid
      FROM t_table_log
      GROUP BY id
      ) llog
    ON llog.id = clog.id
    INNER JOIN t_table_r q
    ON q.id = clog.id
    INNER JOIN sum_table cdr
    ON cdr.cid     = llog.maxcid
    WHERE q.uid       > 1
    AND cid         > 0
```

The total number of rows in the table **sum_table** in **Schema1** is 7612576 and in **Schema2** is 3197076. The column **cid** which is used in the join is indexed in the table **sum_table** in Schema1 and **Schema2** but in the query plan it does a **Indexed Scan** for the table **sum_table** in **Schema1** and **Full Scan** in the table **sum_table** in **Schema2**

I had followed the steps in [Query does full table scan even with indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092058/query-does-full-table-scan-even-with-indexes) but it did not work out

**Schema1** query Plan

[image]

**Schema2** Query Plan

[image]

There is no stale Stats in the index in **Schema2**

Anybody please let me know why it is behaving like this

Comment: Why do you think Oracle should use index scan? What are estimated rowcounts of join predicates? How high they are relative to the overall rowcount of the participating tables? How "wide" is the table compared to the index? There're so little details in your question. Please, provide table definitions with indexes and a query execution plan.

Comment: Hi @astentx, Added the Query Plan

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra join with the inner view `llog`. You can get the same with just one scan of `t_table_log`:

```sql
with clog as (
    SELECT
         id
        ,c_id
        ,MAX(c_id) over(partition by id) AS maxcid
    FROM t_table_log
)
SELECT 
    clog.id,
    clog.c_id,
    cdr.attr_number,
    cdr.cnumber
FROM clog
    INNER JOIN t_table_r q
        ON q.id = clog.id
    INNER JOIN sum_table cdr
        ON cdr.cid     = clog.maxcid
WHERE q.uid       > 1
  AND cdr.cid     > 0;
```

And most likely it's better to use HASH join in this case (I think CBO should choose it automatically, so you don't need to care about it).

Comment: Thanks, but there is no problem in the query I use the same query which I had shared in **Schema1** and **Schema2** in **Schema1** the index is used but in **Schema2** index is not used

Comment: @Rajesh you scan `t_table_log` twice, though it's enough to scan it once. In this case it doesn't even need any index...

Comment: The issue of index in the table `sum_table` only not `t_table_log`